# How to make this image clickable in React?

Tags: reactjs, image, onclick

I've tried using `<a>` and `<Link to="">` as well but the image is not clickable. Now I've used click events still the image is not clickable. How to make this image clickable and redirect to a webpage?

```
import '../index.css';
import LinkedinLogo from '../assets/linkedin.png';
// import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const SocialMedia = () => {

  const link= () => {         
    window.location.href = "https://www.linkedin.com/";
  }


  return (
    <div className="bottom absolute">
        {/* <Link to="https://www.linkedin.com/"> */}
         <img src={LinkedinLogo} alt="Linkedin logo" onClick={link}/>
        {/* </Link> */}
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default SocialMedia;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is workable.

What's problem did you get?

```
export default function App() {
    const link = () => {
        window.location.href = 'https://www.linkedin.com/'
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='bottom absolute'>
                <img
                    alt='Linkedin logo'
                    onClick={link}
                    src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```